# "Could not create connection to database server." Docker MySql and SpringBoot app compose error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have created a simple spring boot app to communicate with MYSQL via Docker using the same network. Once I run docker-compose up command then following errors have occurred.
[java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm1Dw.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwUuG.png)

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  project:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      -SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/spring?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
 
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=spring
    volumes:
      - spring:/data/db
volumes:
 spring:
```

here is my yaml file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring?
serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.database=mysql
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

here is my app properties file

I tried recreating over and over again, prune all the files(network image container) in Docker. Tried creating network via Terminal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it would be more helpful if you add your `pom.xml` or `gradle` configs and your `application.yml`. However, make sure to have the following:

1. The correct dependency with a compatible version:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.16</version>
 </dependency>
```

In your `application.properties`

```
 server.port=8080
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<dbname>
 spring.datasource.username=<username>
 spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

host will be localhost if you are running your application locally, if your spring boot is in a container in your case it should be as you mentioned `mysqldb`. You also need to make sure that your database schema is already created

Your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'    # specify a version
services:
  mysqldb:     # container-name
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<password>
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=<dbname>
      - MYSQL_USER=<user-name>
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=<password>

    volumes:
      - app-data:/var/lib/mysql

  spring-boot:
    ports:
      [8080:8080]
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

volumes:
  app-data:
```

Comment: Hi I edited again with the files you said. I will try with the additions based on your advice. Will update if it works. Thank you

Comment: Did it work with the files above? if not do state the the problem you are facing

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. It still gives the communication error.

Comment: if possible provide a link for your source code so i would be able to further check what is causing the issue